# Assign function.call to a variable

Tags: javascript, function, call, first-class-functions

I have this code

```
var a = function(){}
var b = a.call
b() // TypeError: b is not a function
```

`typeof b` is `'function'` and `console.log(b)` shows `ƒ call() { [native code] }`.

Can someone please explain this behaviour?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? seems rather strange.

Comment: @Andy: The OP probably thought that `a` would be automatically bound to `.call`. There are legit uses for such a bound function, when done correctly. Like if you anticipate receiving an array of items that should be the arguments of `a`, but the first array item is actually meant to be its `this` value. So if you bind `a` to `call` and store it, you can then invoke it like `boundA.apply(null, args)`, or in modern environments, `boundA(...args)`.

Comment: i.e. the reason to use this is ability to switch context for `a`

Comment: @epascarello because I don't want to write `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is that `.call()` requires a function to be the `this` value when invoked, but you've detached it from `a`, so there's no more relationship there.

So because `b`, which is `Function.prototype.call`, has been given no function for a `this` arg, it has no valid function to invoke, so it gives an error.

If you did this, it'll work:

```
var b = a.call.bind(a);
```

That's because now the `a` function is bound as the `this` value of `.call()`.

Another way would be to use `.call` to invoke `.call`.

```
var b = a.call;
b.call(a);
```

Now you're setting the `a` function to the `this` value of `b` (which again is the `Function.prototype.call` method), but you're doing it at the point of invocation.

Comment: Strange that it gives the TypeError of `b` not being a function, when `typeof b === "function"`.

Comment: @JaredSmith: The message is in reference to the `this` value within `b`, since it expects a function. So right now it's getting `undefined` as the `this` value, so it's basically trying to invoke `undefined()` internally.

Comment: I don't think so. If one does this `var a = function(){};var b = a.call;b(function(){});` it still fails. It even fails if you do `b(a)`.

Comment: @JaredSmith: That's because you're passing the function as a regular argument to `Function.prototype.call`, instead of as its `this` value. Change it to `b.call(function(){})`

Comment: ...Remember, when you do `a.call("foo")`, the `a` function gets automatically set as the `this` value of `.call()`, but when you do `var b = a.call`, to set the `this` value of `.call`, you need to do it manually, because the magic behavior of setting `this` via the property member syntax can no longer be achieved.

Comment: ...so basically `var b = a.call; b.call(function(){});` is the same as doing `Function.prototype.call.call(function(){})`

Comment: ...or to put it better, all these are equivalent: `a.call("foo");` ... `var b = a.call; b.call(a, "foo");` ... `Function.prototype.call.call(a, "foo");`